# javascript / jquery: create and post virtual form

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript, I have some data that I want send as a post (NOT ajax). It should act the same as if the user had clicked a submit button. However, I do not have an actual form. The data is collected from the page into various variables, including an array that I encode as json.

I could create an html form with display:none, place the values into this form, and then trigger the invisible submit button. Is there a better way?

Comment: is there any reason for not using AJAX?

Comment: i guess you are looking for this:
http://www.blakepell.com/Main/BlogEntry.aspx?EntryID=30cb4de1-7aab-4798-966b-ab66f629b899

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way of doing this outside of ajax is probably the way you describe with an invisible form. Strange problem though.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus. I want to update the browser, which is why I am not using AJAX.

Comment: Then yah just go for a normal form submit with an invisible form. Or use ajax and force a refresh with JS I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want/can't use Ajax, then you have to do it with a form, which is going to refresh your browser:

```
 $('<form action="urlToServer" method="POST"></form>')
    .append('<input name="data" value="' + yourJSONData + '" />')
    .submit()
;
```

Comment: foud a js solution that works well, https://gist.github.com/apeiros/9cb6c5a889ab183fce2f

Answer (score 5):

Poster "Claudio Bredfeldt" is on the right track to do this, but he omits some crucial information necessary to make this work.

Forms cannot submit across all browsers unless they are attached to the DOM. So what you need to do is something more like this:

```
var $form = $('<form action="http://myurl" method="POST">');
$form.append('<input name="name" value="bob" />');
$form.appendTo($('body')).submit();
```

Optionally you may want to attach some css to the form so that it doesn't appear to the user when you cause the form post event to occur. You also may optionally want to "remove" the form element after posting so that a "back" event will not mis-display depending on browser cache behavior.